# How can I initialize a UITableView added to a .xib in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I'm adding a xib into my view controller like:

```
MyControllerOfXib *myCOntrolXib = [[MyControllerOfXib alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width, height)];
```

In this xib I have a label and a UItableView. The UIlabel is easy to add text:

```
myCOntrolXib.label.text = @"someText";
```

But how can I initialize the tableView? What need I then, Could I use

```
 myCOntrolXib.table.delegate = self;
```

Without problems?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your UITableView from the initWithFrame method in your subclass.

After that you can set the delegate without problems on your mainViewController.

EDIT:
You can call "reload" data etc on your XIB UITableView as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following:

```
CustomView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"YourNibName" owner: nil options: nil] firstObject];
```

Then, don't forget to add the view to the main view using the `addSubview` method. Anyway, now you can do:

```
[view.customProperty doSomething];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom table view cell to populate your table view with elements.
A custom xib would be associated with the tableViewCell and write the following code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath to initialize the cell.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
} 

cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

simpleTableCell is the name of the custom TableViewCell class.

Refer To This Link If you Face Any Issue http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/